# How to map attribute-defined routes from other assembly in asp.net web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

There is another web api project, I want to add that project's controller as a plug-in controller in My asp.net web api project.

First I tried in Global.asax:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile("D:\\CPS\\CPS.WebAPI.dll");
Type type = assembly.GetType("CPS.WebAPI.WebApiConfig");
if (type != null)
{
    MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod("Register");

    var action = (Action<HttpConfiguration>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<HttpConfiguration>), methodInfo);
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(action); //config their web api config
}

GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register); //then my web api config
```

Because we've both implemented `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` ,  it throws exception `a-route-named-ms-attributeroutewebapi-is-already-in-the-route-collection` 。

Then I removed `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();`  of the other project. Although my project can run without error, the attribute-defined routes in that controller was missing.

I also looked into there blogs but none of them can fit my problem:

http://www.strathweb.com/2012/06/using-controllers-from-an-external-assembly-in-asp-net-web-api/

http://www.strathweb.com/2013/08/customizing-controller-discovery-in-asp-net-web-api/

http://www.strathweb.com/2016/05/running-multiple-asp-net-web-api-pipelines-side-by-side/